# How to use WSDL services on Php hosted on XAMPP localhost

Tags: php, web-services, xampp, wsdl, localhost

I am new to web and php…

I am trying to access web service via a wsdl link to get a ping request. The server in point is on a private network that is accessed via LAN and it is off net. I have written the following index.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('api/checkserviceavailability.php');
    $url = "http://ipAddress:port/###########?wsdl";
    $action = "http://*action_Url*";    
    $respone = new RunProcess($url, $action);
    echo "OutPut ".$respone->FirstCall();   
?>
```

The rest of the process is on the directory api/checkserviceavailability.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
class RunProcess{

    private $url ="http://ipAddress:port/###########?wsdl";
    private $action ="http://*action_Url*";

    public function __construct($url, $action){

        $this->url = $url;
        $this->action = $action;    
    }

    public function FirstCall(){

        $soapEnvelopeXml = $this->CreateSoapEnvelope();
        $WebRequest = $this->CreateWebRequest($this->url ,$this->action);
        return $parser = simplexml_load_string($WebRequest);

    }

    public function CreateWebRequest($url, $action){

        $url = $url;
        $headers = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml",
            "Content-length: " . strlen($action),
            "Connection: close",
        );

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $action);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $data = curl_exec($ch); 
        return $data;

    }

    public function CreateSoapEnvelope(){

        $string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:bas="http://*action_Url*"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><bas:checkServiceAvailabilityRequest><requestID/><requestDate/><requestOrigin/><requestMsg>PING</requestMsg></bas:checkServiceAvailabilityRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        return $dom->loadXML($string);

    }

}
```

I had previously ran the code in C# and I got a positive response. Then tried to host the code in xampp in htdocs meaning I will be running it from local host while I am connected to the LAN. I do not know if it is not going through or I am failing because it is LocalHost. And if so, what can I do or use to run and test the code on my machine.

Comment: Why not use the native SOAP functions?

Comment: Honestly I would not know where to start in Php… Open to any change that would achieve something

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Is it possible though to send requests via local host to an external link?